# 2 nodes 2 IP's 1 VPS ubuntu 20.04 how to configure?

Tags: ubuntu, nodes, vps

Want to know how to configure 2 nodes and 2 IP's on 1 VPS ubuntu 20.04. Each node must run on a different IP. I have another IP and have logged in with that IP...can I just make the Node while logged in with different IP and it will use that IP or some other configuring? Thanks

Not much tried yet...just logged into new issued IP and the files look the same

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "node"?

Comment: Like a presearch node or gala node. not sure if I can just login with 2cd IP and setup and it will run on that IP..then login on the primary IP to create another instance that operates via the primary IP. The nodes need to be on separate IP's  thank you